# Could not convert PHP value of type 'integer' to type 'time'

Tags: php, symfony

I have to store hours and minutes. So in my entities I declare the type "Time".
But when I send my form, I get the error :

> Could not convert PHP value '16200' of type 'integer' to type 'time'.
>   Expected one of the following types: null, DateTime

### My entity :

```
     /**
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="time")
     */
    private $timeSupport;

     /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTimeSupport()
    {
        return $this->timeSupport;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $timeSupport
     */
    public function setTimeSupport($timeSupport)
    {
        $this->timeSupport = $timeSupport;
    }
```

### My FormType :

```
->add('timeSupport', TimeType::class, array(
                  'input'  => 'timestamp',
                  'widget' => 'choice',
                  'minutes' => array("0"=>"0","15"=>"15","30"=>"30","45"=>"45"),
                  'label'  => 'Nombres d\'heures de support',
              ));
```

Do you know where my mistake comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine's [Time Type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/types.html#time) uses PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) to handle its data. One way to solve your issue is to change the input field to use `datetime` instead of `timestamp`:

```
->add('timeSupport', TimeType::class, array(
                  'input'  => 'datetime',
                  'widget' => 'choice',
                  'minutes' => array("0"=>"0","15"=>"15","30"=>"30","45"=>"45"),
                  'label'  => 'Nombres d\'heures de support',
              ));
```

If the change above is not possible in your case, you can use a [Data Transformer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html#so-why-use-the-model-transformer) to transform `$timeSupport` from `DateTime` to `timestamp` before showing the form and back to `DateTime` after form submission.